# Prevent span elements from wrapping

Tags: html, css

My UI shows a list of email addresses retrieved by backbone. It is currently rendered as a `span` of `span`s that contain `span`s.  Here's some typical generated html:

[image]

But I am getting breaks inside the `span`s (notice the beginning of angelstwo is on two lines), probably because I am using the wrong html tags (`ul` and `li` sounds better for a list).  It can look like this:

[image]

I tried `div`s but I got one entry per line and I don't want that.

Is there something I can do to make this work with `span`s?  Or should I change to something else like `ul` and `li`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`span` elements are, by default, inline elements. In an *inline formatting context* boxes can wrap. (This is what happens to text when it wraps around a floated image.)

`div` elements are, by default, block elements. In a *block formatting context* the boxes will occupy all available horizontal space (`width: 100%`).

This is why your spans and divs aren't working as you want.

If you switch from `display: inline` to `display: inline-block`, you'll get block-level like behavior, which will prevent wrapping line boxes, but elements will stack horizontally with other inline elements.

W3C References:

- [9.2.2 Inline-level elements and inline boxes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-boxes)
- [9.2.1 Block-level elements and block boxes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes)